# Шрифт одного размера отображается с разным размером на десктопе и и телефоне

Tags: css

Есть [страница](http://777666.ru/Epilage/). Если открывать страницу на телефоне, то в некоторых блоках с абсолютным позиционированием (возможно и в других блоках) один и тот же текст с одинаковым размером шрифта, заданным в CSS, отображается по разному. На мобильном размер шрифта увеличивается и текст не влезает в блок, из-за этого верстка съезжает. Из-за чего это может быть?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: для начала поправте http://joxi.ru/gmvljzOHO9q0Aa )

Comment: спасибо, поправлю :-)

Comment: не до конца поправили — за-кан-чи-ва-е-тся. )

Comment: вопрос, кстати, непонятен — покажите сравнение мобильный / десктоп и приведите код, который описывает эти блоки.

Comment: Я не могу сделать скриншоты с телефона.